# Break out of if else loop without breaking out of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, break

I was making an program in Python and I needed to break out of if else lop without breaking out of while loop.

Current code (incomplete code just for example. Not full code.):

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, time1, link)
        while self.isItNow == False:
            self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M")
            print(self.current_time)
            if str(self.current_time) == self.time1:
                webbrowser.open(self.link, new=1)
                self.isItNow = True
            else:
                print("Current Time =", self.current_time,". Retrying again in 5 seconds")
                time.sleep(5)
                break
```

I wanted to break the else and start the if loop again but I can't do it because it breaks out of the while loop.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: if..else is not a loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Else is not a loop, but you can immediately go to the next loop iteration by using `continue`.

Also... If you just want to break out of the else statement, I'm not sure why you do because do don't have any code below that line...

Comment: :( can't : https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811498945955102750/854586467384426506/unknown.png

Comment: Alright just wait then it's not good to ask new questions in comments. Also while that cooldown is happening you should take some time to restructure your code, there are a lot of better ways to do what you're trying to accomplish. Have fun programming!

Answer (score 2):

Try using continue statement [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:~:text=The%20continue%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:%7E:text=The%20continue%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops).